# Display a “Splash Screen” in IIS while server is starting application

Tags: iis, startup, iis-8

Our web app has got pretty hefty, and takes a long time to launch on first load. The end-user sees 15-20 seconds of spinning progress bars until the login page. Once the first user has loaded, it's pretty instant to view the login page again.

I want to display a "The website is loading, please wait." in a responsive manner so that the end-user isn't left wondering what's happening.

Someone mentioned that they thought this might be possible with IIS8, but wasn't sure how.

I've not been able to find anything with an internet search, so I suspect it isn't possible, but in theory it should be fairly easy, and the App_Offline functionality exists, so I am still hopeful.

Can anyone confirm or deny whether this functionality is available, and if so, how to get to it?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't heard about a splash screen option but have a look at [this](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization)

Hope this helps.